# How should I handle questions offering money for a solution?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754014/i-need-help-adding-a-welcome-pop-up-confirming-21-and-over) offering money for someone to help them:

> I need help adding a 21 plus confirmation pop up on my big cartel page. Any advice would be welcome or email me if you wanna do the work and we can talk compensation [email redacted]

I flagged it as "too broad" since even without the offer the question basically amounted to "write this entire feature for me" but I wasn't sure if I should have taken any other steps. Should I have edited it to remove that part? Would this qualify as spam? Would a custom mod flag have been better?

Or suppose that the question itself was otherwise on-topic. What would be the appropriate action in that case?

Comment: Editing advice:  if you think the question is poor *in spite* of the offer of money, then there's no real benefit to editing it.

Comment: FYI that post has since been deleted.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I figured it would be. The text I've quoted was the entire question.